# packagemaker run shell script

Tags: bash, packagemaker

I'm using PackageMaker to install an app update and want to add a preinstall script to delete some files in the `/Applications/` folder.  The script is simply:

```
#!/bin/bash
rm /Applications/...
```

etc.

If I run this script with Terminal using

```
bash preinstall.sh
```

it works fine.

However, when I add it to PackageMaker and run the .mpkg file the script opens in Text Edit but does not run.  How do I get it to run but not open?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are adding scripts in a wrong way. You can go through 
[this](http://macinstallers.blogspot.in/2012/07/scripting-in-installer-packages.html)
link which has detailed explanation about scripting in Packagemaker and a sample script as well.

Comment: While the link you provided contains some useful information about referencing paths from the installer, it really doesn't address the issue I'm having at all.  I really don't have any indication that the script is running at all.  There is nothing in the installer log that indicates that the script ran.